# How to get palette in luminance-preserving grayscale with matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn, color-palette

I am trying to understand how a specific palette would look in luminance-preserving grayscale (e.g. when printed). I am generating the palette using colors [defined safe for colorblind people](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/colorblind/img/colorblindness.palettes.trivial.pdf):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

# http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/colorblind
cblind = [mpl.colors.to_hex((213/255, 94/255, 0/255)),
          mpl.colors.to_hex((86/255, 180/255, 233/255)),
          mpl.colors.to_hex((.9, .9, .9))]

### how to convert this palette to grayscale?
cblind_gray =
###

pal = sns.color_palette(cblind)
sns.palplot(pal)
```

How can I do it using matplotlib/seaborn or other python packages?

Comment: The code in your answer creates a grayscale palette. What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: @Goyo Using Color Oracle (http://www.colororacle.org/) which changes the color of your screen to simulate various conditions (in my case luminance-preserving grayscale, which seems to produce the colors when printing a figure in grayscale on paper), the results are different for the second color. Therefore, my code is somehow altering the original color and it displays a different grayscale color than expected. I thought about bringing saturation to 0 but apparently this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: If you want to preserve luminance you should say it in the question.

Comment: @Goyo I updated it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved converting to HSV, setting saturation equal to 0 and re-converting back to rgb:

```
# http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/colorblind
rgbs = [(213/255, 94/255, 0/255), (86/255, 180/255, 233/255), (.9, .9, .9)]

cblind = [mpl.colors.to_hex(r) for r in rgbs]
cblind_gray = [mpl.colors.to_hex(
    mpl.colors.hsv_to_rgb(mpl.colors.rgb_to_hsv(r) * (1,0,1)))
    for r in rgbs]

pal = sns.color_palette(cblind)
sns.palplot(pal)

pal = sns.color_palette(cblind_gray)
sns.palplot(pal)
```

Is this the right way to do it?

#### Update

Apparently it does not work (the second color is different when put in grayscale - I checked with [Color Oracle](http://www.colororacle.org)). Do you know what would it be the reason for this and how to fix it?